# JQuery code to show list breaks after version update to 2.2.4

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Good afternoon!

We have a list like:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul class="sf-menu">
        <li style="display:none;" class="root">
            <a href="#" class="navRoot">Title</a>
            <ul class="sf-menu-sub">
                <li><a href="1">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="2">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="3">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="4">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="5">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="6">6</a></li>
                <li><a href="7">7</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li style="display:none" class="noSubMenu root">
            <a href="8" class="navRoot">8</a>
        </li>

        <li style="display:none" class="noSubMenu root">
            <a href="9" class="navRoot">9</a>
        </li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

And we have script like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#navbar li:has(a)').show();
});
```

Anyhow, in our old version we have an import of:

and now we have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/prism-console-web-1.1/scripts/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/prism-console-web-1.1/scripts/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

What I have noticed is that, on some pages we still have the old import and the list appears normally. However, on pages with the new import, the list does not show.

Has anyone else seen this behavior or know the cause?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any errors that appear within the console? This appears to be [working as expected here](http://jsbin.com/zehoji/edit?html,output).

Comment: Working as expected here too: https://jsfiddle.net/0z9zgdje/

Comment: It probably breaks due to something else. You should create a [mcve] demonstrating the problem